# What settings will be good for taking photos of falling leaves?

Tags: technique, autumn

I've been trying to take good photos of falling leaves but haven't had much success. Has anyone got any tips for me (exposure etc), or do I really need some specialist equipment? (I am using a Canon 1000D (Rebel XS in the US) and the basic kit lens). If you've taken a successful photo of this kind, please post it and the settings/equipment you used.

Comment: Are you hoping to catch them mid flight?

Comment: Having an example of unsuccessful attempts might hint us what you were aiming for and perhaps give better advice. And by the way, welcome!

Comment: I'm curious to see the suggestions, I've never tried this myself, but given falling leaves will be more unpredictable than birds in flight, I expect it would be quite a challenge.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have one picture with leaves, but I used flash to catch them mid-flight.
[image: pic w/ leaves]
(shot on 1/250 sec, f/5.6, ISO 100, there was [CTO-gelled](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-do-i-use-gels-to-make-my-flash-match-the-color-of-the-ambient-light) flash on camera right)

Obviously, we had to throw leaves in the air by ourselves.

If you don't have flash, I'd suggest shutter around 1/250, open aperture as much as you can, focus to half a meter, and then throw leaves to that area. That might result in something interesting. (Just a thought.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it varies, depends on what you're trying to do. But my guess is you'll always need some kind of light: either flash light (as in che's photo) or back light (like I was trying to do in my photo)

[image: yes, there are leaves falling in this photo ;)]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a certainly technically imperfect example (manual focusing quickly in severely windy and hand-chilling conditions....), but relevant because it shows some leaves illuminated (well, overexposed :) by severe flash usage, some only by natural light. Metz 45CT, full blast, on ground several meters away from camera, radio triggered, Series 1 19-35mm wide open (can't remember zoom setting,adapted) on Sony APS-C at ISO 1600, with the original Metz red filter. Would work with any similar camera.